# Underlying driver of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

Does anyone know whether `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` has its own implementation to access SQL Server? Or does it use one of the following clients:

- *OLE DB Provider for SQL Server* (`SQLOLEDB`) (deprecated)
- *SQL Server Native Client* (`SQLNCLI`) (deprecated)
- *OLE DB Driver for SQL Server* (`MSOLEDBSQL`)

Comment: It is its own thing (a managed implementation with a few bits in unmanaged code on .NET Framework but not .NET Core) and shares no code with any of these drivers. (Managed code can be made to use these drivers through OLE DB or ODBC, but  there are few use cases for that.)

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-providers

Comment: Why the question? The answer is well documented. Are you trying to solve a specific problem and assume it may be caused by an obsolete driver?

Comment: What *is* scheduled for deprecation is `System.Data.SqlClient` itself - it's going to be replaced by the open-source [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) at some point in the future

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, the question was just out of curiosity. I'm not trying to solve any particular issue.

Comment: @mu88 you can actually [read the code in Github](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient). It's a separate provider that implements TDS on its own. Check for example the [TdsParser.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/654933a0811ab30b843a20aff051b8d585238505/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs) file

Answer (score 0):

It's derived from DbConnection which is in turn derived straight from Component, so it very much looks like its own implementation.